# Equalities modulo a product hold modulo a factor

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it safe to assume that if $a\equiv b \pmod {35 =5\times7}$

then $a\equiv b\pmod 5$  is also true?

Comment: Yes.  $35\,|\,a-b\implies 5\,|\,a-b$.

Comment: If $a\equiv b\pmod {mn}$ then $a\equiv b\pmod m$.

Comment: $a \equiv b \mod mn$ means that there exists an integer $k$ so that $a = b + k(mn)$ which means there exist and integer $kn$ so that $a = b + (kn)m$ so $a \equiv b \mod m$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "$a \equiv b \text{ mod m}$" is equivalent to "There exists integer k such that $a = b + km$". If there exists $k_1$ such that $a = b +35k_1$, then we can set $k_2=7k_1$, and then $a = b+ 5k_2$. So $a \equiv b \text{ mod 35}$ does in fact imply $a \equiv b \text{ mod 5}$. This also follows trivially from the  Chinese Remainder Theorem: if $a$ and $b$ represent the same element in **Z**$_{35}$, then they also represent the same element in **Z**$_5$x **Z**$_7$.

Comment: Speaking about chinese remainder theorem. Can I use it only when there is a sole x in the equation? suppose 10x is equivalent to 34 mod 63 ... Does the use of CRT is permitted?

Comment: $10x \equiv 34 \mod 63$ means $10x\equiv 34 \mod 9$ or in other words $x \equiv 7 \mod 9$, and that $10x \equiv 34 \mod 7$ or in other words that $3x \equiv 6 \mod 7$. So $x \equiv 2 \mod 7$ and $x \equiv 7\mod 9$ so $x \equiv 16\mod 63$

Answer (score 0):

If $m | c$ and $c | a -b$, then $m |a -b$. Use this and the fact that

$$
a \equiv b \pmod{d} \iff d | a - b
$$

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv b \mod mn \implies mn|a-b$ and as $m|mn$ and $mn|a-b$ then $m|a-b$ so $a\equiv b \mod m$.

(Lemma: Divisibility is transitive. Pf: $a|b$ means there exists an integer, $k$, so that $ak = b$.  $b|c$ means there exists an integer, $j$ so that $bj =c$.  So $a(jk)=c$.  So $a|c$.)

It does not work the other way, of course.  $a\equiv b \mod m \not \implies a\equiv b \mod m$ but we can state:

$a \equiv b \mod m \implies a \equiv b + km \mod mn$ for some $k;0 \le k < n$.  (And by Chinese Remainder theorem we know said $k$ is unique.